# @IBDesignable UIView not calling init within storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, ibdesignable, uibackgroundcolor

I have a `UIView` that is is `@IBDesignable`

```
@IBDesignable
class MyView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInit()
    }

    private func sharedInit(){
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundColor = .blue
    }

}
```

When I place this a `UIView` in the Storyboard, and assigned its class to `MyView` in the **Identity inspector**, the `UIView` still has a default background colour. Why is its background colour not `UIColor.blue` in the Storyboard? And, how can I make it like this, please?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `init` is used in *runtime* - and Interface Builder is *design-time*. While this may not work, look into using `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` for seeing `sharedInit`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Initializer which initialize this view from storyboard will call on runtime, for updating view within storyboard in compile time you should try to include `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` which updates storyboard xib files in compile time.

I suggest you to do multiple things when you are going to create @IBDesignable classes :

1. Mark class with `@IBDesignable` tag
2. Mark `UIView` property with `@IBInspectable`, then you will be able to change the value for this property using **StoryBoard**
3. Set the configuration code in `willSet` of that property which is observer for changes before the property takes the value, or `didSet` after the property received the value.
4. Do your additional setup in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` which is overriding from its super class kind of `UIView`

Simple and easy !

Your code should looks like this :

### Swift 5 :

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class myView: UIView {

  @IBInspectable var storyBoardColor : UIColor = .red {         
    willSet(myVariableNameToCatch) {
      self.backgroundColor = myVariableNameToCatch
    }
   }

  fileprivate func sharedInit(){
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    backgroundColor = storyBoardColor
  }

  override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    sharedInit()
  }
}
```

myView had initial value of red for storyBoardColor and you can change it from storyBoard ;)

[image]

Comment: @thibautnoah hi, i reminded him in section (3), and told him how to implement structre base. the answer could found in section (3), and for the functionality i wanted for everyone to know how does it works.. but thanks maybe i should explain  less.

Comment: @mohamadrezakoohkan the view is not init in the first place.. hence why i said you didn't answer the question. I agree on the inspectable part but you changed the structure of the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

Once you make your view with tag @IBDesignable. next thing is to set your properties with @IBInspectable.

```
@IBDesignable
class MyView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var myBackgroundColour: UIColor? = nil {
        willSet(v) {
            self.backgroundColor = v
        }
    }
   // YOUR EXISTING CODE HERE
}
```

Now, when you set the MyView as a class name in **Identity Inspector**. You will be able to see your inspectable property in **Attributes Inspector**. there you can set the colour and it will be reflected instantly to your custom view.

I don't see any usefulness to set the background colour with your custom property because, UIView has the default property to set the background colour.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2 tested and working. This is the cleanest solution.**

In Xcode make sure `Editor -> Automatically refresh views` is checked.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class BoxView: UIView {

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

1. Create the BoxView.swift file above.
2. Select a UIView in InterfaceBuilder.
3. In the `Identity Inspector` select `Custom Class -> Class to "BoxView"`.
4. In the `Attributes Inspector` set `borderColor`, `borderWidth`, and `borderRadius`.